How to set the parameter using adaptive mpc controller in Simulink for HESS control system?
My problem is I do not know how to set up the adaptive mpc controller.This my first time using the adaptive mpc controller block in Simulink. I want to use this block in order to control the HESS. Before this, I already tried the adaptive pi controller to control the HESS. I want to control power flow and voltage in my HESS.
I expecting to get to know on how to set the mpc for the HESS control system for its power flow and voltage.
